# how to reset all mysql stats?

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql

I can't seem to find a way to reset all the mysql stats (that show in the 'Stats' page in phpmyadmin)

I can reset the Server Traffic section but everything else doesn't get reset (InnoDB stats, handler stats, etc).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a very old feature request, that is still not implemented: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=22875

You can use the "FLUSH STATUS;" command as described in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flush.html but it will only reset session stats, not the global stats.

Answer (score 9):

do a restart of database will reset all stats

**PS :** stat meant for cumulative results